# Remove double quotes from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How do I remove double quotes from an NSString.  Example:

```
//theMutableString: "Hello World"

[theMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:(NSRange){0,[theMutableString length]}]
```

It doesn't seem to work, maybe since I had to escape the " in the replaceOccurrencesOfString?

Comment: I take it's a typo that you use [mString length] to get the length of theMutableString?

Comment: Yep, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `NSMakeRange` function instead of your cast. This'll work:

```
[mString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mString length])];
```

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that. It works without the NSMakeRange (though I encourage the use of NSMakeRange).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's the source of the problem, since it works either way for me, too (although use of `NSMakeRange` is probably better).

Answer (score 4):

How about this ?

```
NSCharacterSet *quoteCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""];
NSString *trimmedString = [toBeTrimmedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:quoteCharset];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the mString bit is a typo. I ran this code and the answer was as expected

```
NSMutableString * theMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"\"Hello World!\""];
NSLog(@"%@",theMutableString);

[theMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:(NSRange){0,[theMutableString length]}];

NSLog(@"%@",theMutableString);

[theMutableString release];
```

Output

```
2010-01-23 15:49:42.880 Stringtest[2039:a0f] "Hello World!"
2010-01-23 15:49:42.883 Stringtest[2039:a0f] Hello World!
```

So it mString was a typo in your question, then your code is correct and the problem is elsewhere. If mString is a typo in your code than that would be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use `NSMakeRange(0, [theMutableString length])` instead of trying to cast an inline struct?

Answer (score 0):

I works perfectly on my end (I copy-pasted your replace line), with both NSMakeRange and the inline struct cast. Are you sure the quotes in your NSString are really the ASCII character 0x22?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```