# Adding NSMutableString to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, string

I'm having some trouble adding a mutable string (that has been changed with replaceOccurrencesOfString) to an array.  This is related to another question I asked: [Remove double quotes from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124860/remove-double-quotes-from-nsstring)

Here is the code

```
//original String
NSString *aString = @"\"Hello World\"";
NSLog(@"Original String: %@",aString);

//craete mutable copy
NSMutableString *mString = [aString mutableCopy];

//remove quotes
[mString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])];
NSLog(@"Mutable String: %@",mString);   

//add to an array
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mString];
NSLog(@"anArray: %@",anArray);
```

And the result:

```
2010-01-25 09:01:15.644 Quotes[20058:a0f] Original String: "Hello World"
2010-01-25 09:01:15.662 Quotes[20058:a0f] Mutable String: Hello World
2010-01-25 09:01:15.663 Quotes[20058:a0f] anArray: (
"Hello World"
)
```

a
As you can see, the string is removed of the quotes in mString but when it's added to the array, it still has the double quotes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the string has a space in it, and so the array is wrapping it in quotes to make sure you understand that the two words go together.  If you were to pull the string back out of the array and search for double quotes, you wouldn't find any.

If the string still had quotes in it and you were to log the array with the quoted string, it would look like:

```
2010-01-25 10:14:37.818 EmptyFoundation[4131:a0f] (
    "\"Hello world!\""
)
```

Comment: Thanks, was racking my brain for why the quotes were still there!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your only seeing

```
2010-01-25 09:01:15.663 Quotes[20058:a0f] anArray: (
"Hello World"
)
```

Because your printing out the description of the array - try

```
NSLog(@"The string is: %@", [anArray objectAtIndex:0])
```

and I'm fairly confident it'll return with

```
The string is : Hello World
```