# Replace double double quotes "" with single double quote "

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove double quotes from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124860/remove-double-quotes-from-nsstring)

I have a string with double double quotes "" that I need to replace with single double quotes ".

I've tried the following but I still end up with double double quotes

```
NSString *str = @"This is a \"\"99\"\" string";
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"\"" withString: @"\""];
```

Initially the string is: This is a ""99"" string

After the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: This is a ""99"" string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting `str` to contain your modified string. Instead, you should be looking at the return value of the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` function:

```
NSString *str = @"This is a \"\"99\"\" string";
NSString *result =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"\"" withString: @"\""];

NSLog(@"before: %@ after: %@", str, result);
```

NSString objects are immutable. If you want str to be mutable, look into NSMutableString: [documentation link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

The method you are calling doesn't change the original NSString. It returns a new NSString with the replacements you've asked for.

Save the new string and use that.